# Voice chat for Netcode for Game Objects Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, lan

I am developing a small platformer for a school project. The requirements are that the game must run on LAN, so we are using Unity's Netcode for Game Objects and that's working perfectly, and also that it must have a voice chat. I have been struggling to find a voice chat that works with Netcode for Game Objects.

So far I've found Dissonance, but since it's a school project I would prefer a free solution. I've also found several github repositories with different solutions but I'm not sure how they could be integrated with Netcode for Game Objects. I also found Photon Voice, but as far as I understand that wouldn't meet the LAN requirement.

If anyone knows a solution for this I would be very thankful. I am quite new to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

With Netcode Unity released also Vivox which is a service that does what I think you're looking for: [Vivox Unity](https://unity.com/products/vivox?_ga=2.54813480.240751236.1669021166-319065095.1668423078)

This is the documentation [Documentation](https://docs.vivox.com/v5/general/unity/15_1_190000/en-us/Default.htm#Unity/Unity.htm%3FTocPath%3DUnity%7C_____0)